# Keep div in desired place with css, external content

Tags: php, css, html

Here is my problem.

I have a function, PHP class side, that reads all data from one table, create all divs with specific CSS ids, puts the data in place, and in one of them the data comes from an external source, an external php file.

So I do this in the code:

```
$Return .= "</div><div id='PostTitleComplete'><strong>Post Completo</strong></div><div id='PostText'>";
$Return .= include($row['PathFile']);
$Return .= "</div><div id='PostData'>";
```

All divs are opening and closing properly, all data worked correctly until i changed the data that used to be loaded fom the table to the div here the included file is know.

The external file only have HTML code generated by HTML copy from Visual studio and its all good to, ive used to use that html code in other places, no problem till know.

So, the CSS are the ones that follow:

This is the CSS used to hold the included file:

```
#PostText {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This is the parent of the above one:

```
#PostBody {
    border: #00C 1px solid;
    width:80%;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    float:left;
}
```

and this ones are the CSS from the included file:
One div includes the one, just like the name says.

```
#FirstOne {
    border: #000080 1px solid; 
    color: #000; 
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, Monospace; 
    font-size: 9pt;
}
#SecondOne {
    background: #000080; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

I used this same structure in one blog, but instead of an include file I used data from the table, so i think the problem are from the CSS. This is the result i get. This Giang Div is totally adjustable to the screen size, but it stays up there instead of here the arrow points and here the include is printed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

The value `1` is returned because the `include`-statement was performed successfully.

If the included file **doesn't contain** any **code that needs to run**, you can use `file_get_contents()`:

```
$Return .= "</div><div id='PostTitleComplete'><strong>Post Completo</strong></div><div id='PostText'>";
$Return .= file_get_contents($row['PathFile']);
$Return .= "</div><div id='PostData'>";
```

As a reference, if the include file **does have code that has to be executed**, use output buffering:

```
function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return false;
}
$Return .= "</div><div id='PostTitleComplete'><strong>Post Completo</strong></div><div id='PostText'>";
$Return .= get_include_contents($row['PathFile']);
$Return .= "</div><div id='PostData'>";
```

Above code is taken from the [PHP-manual (include-statement, example 6)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: The $Return .= file_get_contents($row['PathFile']); worked perfectly, thks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using incude try using file_get_content()

```
$Return .= "</div><div id='PostTitleComplete'><strong>Post Completo</strong></div>";
$Return .= "<div id='PostText'>";

$Return .= file_get_content($row['PathFile']);

$Return .= "</div><div id='PostData'>";
```